# Cyrillic alphabet with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL Server database, and I need to store some texts written using Cyrillic alphabet.

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to enter, view and manipulate data. But when I insert data like

```
Insert into EBook (TitleID, Title, ContentFile) 
values (N'титул', N'король голый', N'чего-то там еще');
```

and then do SELECT, I see only ???? instead of the texts.

I don't even know whether the data was stored incorrectly, or the Studio cannot correctly 
display it. 
How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What **datatype** are those columns??

In order to store e.g. Cyrillic characters, they **must** be `nvarchar(x)`

I see the exact same phenomenom: with `varchar(100)` the data goes in fine but comes out as nothing but questions marks ??????? - but with `nvarchar(100)` everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried ntext, then nvarchar(50), but it didn't help. :(

Comment: @DavidShochet: BTW, if you're on SQL Server 2005 or newer: *don't* use `NTEXT` anymore, it's been deprecated. If you really need tons of room for text, use an `nvarchar(max)` instead - much better!